# How to check if rule value is substring of data value? (json-logic-js)

Tags: jsonlogic

I want to accomplish a simple operation: checking if the rule value is a substring of the data value.

Let's say the rule value is `'check'` and the data value is `'checking'`. It must return `true` since the rule value is a substring of the data value.

Here is my current rule:

```
{
  "and": [
    {
      "in": [
        {
          "var": "ACTION1"
        },
        "check"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is my data:

```
{
  "ACTION1": "check the dictionary"
}
```

Currently, this setup won't return true unless we place the rule value and data value in the opposite order. However, I don't want to do this since the data value is dynamic.

Can you please help me?

---

> I can't find `json-logic-js` tag. sorry for tagging `jsonlogic`

Answer (score 0):

i fixed by transferring the value at the top of `var` object.

rule data

```
{
  "and": [
    {
      "in": [
        "check", // transferred it above
        {
          "var": "ACTION1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Basically,

- Place the value before `var` object - `dataValue.includes(ruleValue)` *(js)*
- Place the value after `var` object - `ruleValue.includes(dataValue)` *(js)*

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired behavior of checking if the rule value is a substring of the data value, you can use the `contains` operator instead of `in`.

The `contains` operator checks if the data value contains the specified substring.

Here's how you can modify your rule:

```
{
  "and": [
    {
      "contains": [
        {
          "var": "ACTION1"
        },
        "check"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

the rule will return true if the data value `check the dictionary` contains the substring `"check"`, which aligns with your requirement.

Here is the sample that I tried running in the simple Json logic playground **https://jsonlogic.com/play.html**

[Executed rule and data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j5Ph.png)

Comment: your answer is incorrect. In your **executed rule and data** can you scroll down a little more, you will see an error `Unrecognized operation contains`.Thank you for answering, I already resolved the issue, please check my answer.